# twitter bootstrap fonts not showing in production rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In development mode, my custom css's font using twitter bootstrap works fine.

But in production mode, the font displayed is not the correct font in the css.

I had done rake assets:precompile:all in development first before going to production.

Why is it so?

Comment: Fonts are imports from googlle font api or you store them as files?

Comment: imports from google api. i am seeing this in css:

@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Telex);

Update - I am using the one of the themes from bootswatch.com.

Comment: Check your css if the @imports are in the very beginning of your minified css.

Comment: I'm using the non-minified version of  the css and it is at the very beginning of the css.

Comment: Hm, and what happens when you inspect the element that has wrong font with chrome dev tools? `font-family` is correct?

Comment: the bootstrap css file in question is not listed in "Matched CSS rules" for production, while is listed in the working development.

in development, the navbar (with the font in question) loads the css while the production didn't and used application.css instead.

Comment: Run `rake assets:precompile` in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on cortex's answer.

Running

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

in production, makes the problem go away.